# Making a random array of numbers, with each number being unique

Tags: vb.net

I'd like for a string of 24 numbers to appear in the text box, and then for each to have a random number from 0 to 23.

so far I have the following code made, but it makes a duplicate number appear occasionally.

```
        Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Randomize()
            Dim Output As String = String.Empty
            Dim NumberArray(24) As Integer
            For n As Integer = 0 To 23
                Dim RandomNumber As Integer = CInt(Int(Rnd() * 25) + 1)
                NumberArray(n) = RandomNumber
                Output &= "Index #" & n.ToString & Space(4) & NumberArray(n) & vbCrLf
            Next
            TextBox1.Text = Output
        End Sub
    End Class
```

any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `CInt(Int(Rnd() * 25) + 1)`  returns a number 1 to 25.  `Dim RandomNumber As Integer = CInt(Int(Rnd() * 25) + 1)` is VB.Net syntax not VBA.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about VBA? Looks like VB.Net to me

Comment: Since all the numbers are 0 to 24 will appear in the array,  I would populate the array sequentially in one loop and then randomize the elements in the array with a second loop.